# ngx datepicker Quick select ranges not work

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I would like to use the **Quick select ranges** option of the nxg datepicker, but not work for me.
I have installed in angular with npm, i have imported the module in app.module.ts, and i have imported the css, everything works except the Quick select ranges option.

This is the code on the input tag:

```
<input (bsValueChange)="changeDate($event)" type="text" placeholder="Daterangepicker" class="form-control" [bsConfig]="{ ranges: ranges, containerClass: 'theme-red' }" [bsValue]="bsValue" bsDaterangepicker>
```

and i pass in the component the ranges value

```
ranges = [{
    value: [new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 7)), new Date()],
    label: 'Last 7 Days'
  }, {
    value: [new Date(), new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 7))],
    label: 'Next 7 Days'
  }];
```

what am I doing wrong?

Thank's for any help.

Comment: Why do you mean it doesn't work? For me, your code works https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dpwwgi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue. Custom range selector is available in datepicker of ngx-bootstrap version 5.6.0 and above. Check your package.json, to verify the version of ngx you are using. I upgraded it to 5.6.0 and it started working

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25788849)

Comment: custom ranges in ngx-datepicker only available in ngx-bootstrap version 5.6.0 and above.That is the only solution

Comment: If that is the solution, then the question is not well-formed.